# When an action is dispatched, state of another reducer is removed. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use Redux in my project for first time. I have multiple reducers and and actions. When the first action is dispatched, state is changed. It looks okey. After dispatching second action, state is changed again but the previous changes are removed. I mean, when 'FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS' is dispatched companyName is changed and companyDesc set to initial value. Then 'FETCH_INITIAL_MEMBER' is dispatched and companyName is removed but companyDesc is still there and member payloads are also changed. What is my mistake? Thanks.

I tried many ways to solve this but still continue. I check this on Redux DevTools.

memberReducer

```
const initialState = {
  username: '',
  companyId: '',
  isAdmin: '',
  photo: '',
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_INITIAL_MEMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.payload.username,
        companyId: action.payload.companyId,
        isAdmin: action.payload.isAdmin,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

companyReducer

```
const initialState = {
  companyName: 'companyName',
  companyDesc: 'companyDesc',
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        companyName: action.payload.companyName,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

memberAction

```
const fetchInıtıalMember = async muuid => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/member/${muuid}`)
    .then(response => {
      const username = response.data.mname;
      const isAdmin = response.data.misAdmin;
      const companyId = response.data.cid;

      store.dispatch({
        type: FETCH_INITIAL_MEMBER,
        payload: {
          username,
          isAdmin,
          companyId,
        },
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {});
};
```

companyAction

```
const fetchCompanyInformations = () => {
  store.dispatch({
    type: FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS,
    payload: { companyName: 'dispacthedCompanyName' },
  });
};
```

**Edit:** 
The code above is correct. My mistake is about importing the constants. This Redux implementation works well. I was storing all action type constant in a types.js file. I import this type constants in the another files wrongly. After changing it my problem is solved.

Comment: what are the string values of `FETCH_INITIAL_MEMBER` and `FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS`?

Comment: @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd They are just string constants for action type. I store them in a types.js file `const FETCH_INITIAL_MEMBER = 'FETCH_INITIAL_MEMBER';
const FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS = 'FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS';`

Comment: cool, and I assume you're using `combineReducers` to combine the two into one?

Comment: Yes, like this `export default combineReducers({
  member: memberReducer,
  company: companyReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
});`

Comment: ok. reason I'm asking all this is because it seems like both cases are being caught at the same time, making me think they're dispatching the same type string. Can you add your action functions to the question too please?

Comment: I edited the question. These actions are dispatched when two components are mounted on the same page. Is it problem? I thought because of the same state, it won't be problem.

Comment: just before you dispatch, can you just console.log the `FETCH_INITIAL_MEMBER` and `FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS` vars? the way you're doing it **should** work properly

Comment: @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd you were right :) You saved my hours. Thank you! In the console, the constant are undefined. I was focusing to the wrong part from the beginning. It is just importing problem. I was using 'export default' and 'import  FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS'. I changed it to 'export { } ' import { FETCH_COMPANY_INFORMATIONS }'. It works fine now.  After that, I'll ask here more carefully for the problems.